# Angular 5: error thrown after `ng serve --prod` only "Property 'id' does not exist on type..."

Tags: angular

I have an error that is only thrown after `ng serve --prod` but after `ng serve` everything works fine.

## The Error

```
ERROR in component.html(5,24): : Property 'id' does not exist on type 'ProductModel'.
```

## The HTML

```
<div *ngIf="product?.id">{{product.id}}</div>
```

## My Component

```
product: ProductModel;
constructor( public bcProductService: BcProductService) { 
    this.bcProductService.getProductById(id).subscribe(single => {
        return this.product = single.data;
    });
}
```

## Questions

- am i setting `this.product` wrong? Why does it work on dev and not `--prod`?
- It seems like there is an extra layer of errors on `ng build --prod`
  how do I make sure i see all errors in dev mode? is it as simple as building in `--prod`? but what about environment.ts vars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not user `product?.id` instead use `product && product.id ? true : false` or create method `productExists()` which return true/false for `if`. - this is probably connected with AoT (Ahead of Time - probably used in production compilation) - i found this information in [this angular-framework](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter#aot-donts).

Comment: This error went away when I changed an `any[]` to `any` in my model. and your answer was needed also